# Can I stop the execution of an infinite loop in Scala REPL?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

Can I stop the execution of an infinite loop in Scala REPL?
Type this and try to stop it without quitting the REPL.

```
while(true){}
```

I thought something like Ctrl-C would work.

Comment: Ctrl-C works for me on Mac OS X.

Comment: Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Break doesn't work on Windows 7

Comment: Which version of Scala are you using? There were some improvements in 2.9 so that this will work without quitting the REPL. Ctrl-C should work, also in Windows. *edit* - just tried it out on Scala 2.9.0.1 on Windows Vista and indeed Ctrl-C doesn't work...

Comment: Currently CTRL-C doesn't work on windows. See my edited answer below. But I guess this should work if the binding is removed. I asked on the scala mailing list (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-language/KfHp0JXdOI0). Let's see whats happening.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on your scala version. If you are already on scala 2.9 it will work by just using CTRL-C. It might take some time untile the command reaches the REPL but it will abort your infinite loop at some time.

If you are on an older version of scala (before 2.9). There is no way to stop execution. On those versions CTRL-C will lead to termination of the whole scala REPL.

The change was introduced with Scala 2.9.0.RC2. See the [changelog (part: Repl Improvements)](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/9314) for further details.

This doesn't work on windows, since the Scala REPL keybindings of the scala windows distribution override CTRL-C with "toggle overtype mode". Type

```
 scala> :keybindings
```

on a windows system to view the whole comment for this binding. I guess this is a bug on windows.

Comment: It doesn't work for me on Scala 2.11.8 interpreter either (running on Mac OS X Terminal). I tried `Stream.from(1) foreach println` and hitting Ctrl-C. It aborts the whole process.

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/PqK6GkZhJK0 which seems to say that this ability was removed (?!) some time before 2.10. And AFAICT it's still not fixed: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6302 Ugh.