# Hotkey to stop REPL?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

Is there a hotkey to stop/exit the Scala REPL ?

Example: I start the Scala REPL from SBT with command `console`, then do something stupid like an endless loop and want to end the REPL without closing the shell at all. Something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (which all do not work).

**Update:** 
Used OS: Windows 7 64 Bit.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> exists SBT and the REPL, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> does NOT exit the REPL when I am in an endless loop like

```
while(true) prinln("test")
```

Is there a way to get out of the endless loop with a hotkey without closing the shell ? Or is this not possible because the REPL will not react to hotkeys until the loop is through (which will, of course, not happen in this case) ?

Comment: hm what OS are you using? Because ctrl+c seems to do the trick for me (under MacOS 10.6)

Comment: are you launching from sbt, because you say `console`?

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk Oh, I see, this seems to be an OS specific problem. I use Windows 7 64 Bit Edition. Ctrl+C does not work for me.

Comment: @0__ Yes, you are right. I made this clear in my question now.

Comment: Ok. I can confirm that Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Z also quit sbt on OS X.

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248884/can-i-stop-the-execution-of-an-infinite-loop-in-scala-repl

Answer (score 2):

The following works with Scala 2.10.0-M6, but in 2.9.2 you can probably achieve something similar using `:wrap` in REPL power mode.

Assume that the REPL is started from sbt via `sbt console`—without loss of generality (you may otherwise just put the `ReplUtil` class on scala's class path). Assume the following class is on the class path, e.g. its source is at `src/main/scala/ReplUtil.scala`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.{Executors, ExecutorService, TimeoutException, TimeUnit}
import concurrent._

object ReplUtil {
  @volatile private var exec: ExecutorService = _
  @volatile private var threads = Set.empty[ Thread ]
  private def freshPool() { exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool() }
  freshPool()

  private implicit def context = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService( exec )

  def panic() {
    (new Thread {
      override def run() {
        try {
          exec.shutdownNow()
          exec.awaitTermination( 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS ) 
        } finally {
          val th = threads
          threads = Set.empty
          th.foreach( _.stop )
          freshPool()
        }
      }
    }).start()
  }    

  def spawn[T](t: => T) = {
    var futPrint = false
    val fut = future {
       val th = Thread.currentThread()
       threads += th
       val res = try { t } finally { threads -= th }
       if( futPrint ) println( "<calculation done>\n" + res )
       t
    }
    try {
      Await.result( fut, util.Duration( 4, TimeUnit.SECONDS )).toString
    } catch {
      case e: TimeoutException =>
        futPrint = true
        "<ongoing calculation>"
    }
  }
}
```

Then the following will activate the semi-asynchronous REPL:

```
$ sbt console
...
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0-M6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_33).
...
scala> import ReplUtil.panic
import ReplUtil.panic

scala> :power
** Power User mode enabled - BEEP WHIR GYVE **
...

scala> power.intp.setExecutionWrapper("ReplUtil.spawn")

scala> 2+2
res1: Int = 4

scala> Thread.sleep(6000); 33
<ongoing calculation>

scala> <calculation done>
res2: Int = 33

scala> while(true) { Thread.sleep(2000); println( "Zzz" )}
Zzz
Zzz
<ongoing calculation>
scala> panic

scala> [error] (pool-5-thread-1) java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
...
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
...
```

Comment: How can a Q be +6 while the A is +0?  Anyway, given the demise of :wrap, REPL needs generic templating, with built-ins for "timed," "interruptible," etc.

Answer (score 0):

related to the topic is a useful <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> key binding for exiting non terminating evaluations of a program when inside an eclipse scala worksheet.